# Nginx server returns 308 status code when trying to proxy pass to external hosted service

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, proxypass, openresty

I am trying to proxy pass one of my nginx server endpoint to an external service that intern redirects calls to another service with in it.
my config looks like below

```
location = /proxy/live {
        proxy_pass <externalservice ip:port>/live;
        proxy_pass_request_body on;
    }
```

with in the external service **/live** endpoint redirects to another service that is unknown to my nginx server.
with the above configuration I am getting 308 error code (redirection issue). while trying to access **/proxy/live** endpoint. How can i resolve this issue and get the proxy_pass call through external service up till the end service.

Comment: You can try adding a trailing backslash to the URL in your `proxy_pass` directive.

Comment: Hi @IVO GELOV thanks for the comment. Adding trailing slash actually worked. I changed the proxy_pass to proxy_pass <externalservice ip:port>/live/ and it worked . Can you please elaborate on how this worked and also would recommend to add this as answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

If the URL argument of the `proxy_pass` directive ends with a trailing slash - then the location path `is not` appended to this URL. However, if the URL does not end with a trailing slash - then the location path `is` appended to this URL when passing to the upstream.

This is not very clear from the [nginX documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) where they simply refer to the `proxy_pass` as being either specified `with an URI` or `without an URI`:

- If the `proxy_pass` directive is specified with a URI, then when a request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive:

```
location /name/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/remote/;
}
```

- If `proxy_pass` is specified without a URI, the request URI is passed to the server in the same form as sent by a client when the original request is processed, or the full normalized request URI is passed when processing the changed URI:

```
location /some/path/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
}
```